# Push multiple objects in an new array makes array undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I used API calls GET JSON data, filtering it and pushing objects into a new array. However, the elements of the array are undefined types instead of objects.

```
function filterDataAtSource(city, vacTypeFilters) {
    var filteredFeatures = [];

    getData().then(function (geojson) {
        var features = geojson.features
        features.forEach(element => {
            if (element.properties.City === city) {
                console.log("type of element :", typeof (element));
                filteredFeatures.push(element);
            }
        });
    })
    console.log("typeof child:", typeof (filteredFeatures[0])); /* undefined type here */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with asynchronous code and need to connect in to the promise chain to avoid looking at the variable value too early.

Something like this might work better:

```js
function filterDataAtSource(city, vacTypeFilters) {        
    // return the promise
    return getData().then(function(geojson) {
        var filteredFeatures = [];
                    
        geojson.features.forEach(element => {                                           
            if (element.properties.City === city) {
                console.log("type of element :", typeof(element));
                filteredFeatures.push(element);
            }
        };

        // return this to minimize visibility
        return filteredFeatures;
     }); 
});

filterDataAtSource('Paris', {})
    .then((filteredFeatures) => {
        console.log("typeof child:", typeof(filteredFeatures[0]));
    });
```

And you can play around with the factoring of the code by using async functions. For example:

```js
const filterDataAtSource = async (city, vacTypeFilters) =>
    (await getData())
        ?.features
        ?.filter(({ properties: { City } }) => City === city)

// ensure you are in an async function, or an environment that supports global async
const filteredFeatures = await filterDataAtSource('Paris', {})
console.log("typeof child:", typeof(filteredFeatures[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You add values to the array only by condition **element.properties.City === city**
Are you sure that the condition is met at least once?
Have you checked the length of the array **filteredFeatures** at the output?

undefined can be for the simple reason that there is no 0 element in the array

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving values before they exist because of calling an asynchronous function.

You could try this also. Make `filterDataAtSource()` asynchronous to `await getData()`.

```
async function filterDataAtSource(city, vacTypeFilters) {
    var filteredFeatures = [];
    const geojson = await getData();
    console.log("typeof child:", typeof(filteredFeatures[0])); /* undefined type here */
    
    var features = geojson.features;
             
    features.forEach(element => {     
        if (element.properties.City === city) {
            console.log("type of element :", typeof(element));
            filteredFeatures.push(element);
        }
    });
}
```